# CasperjsJS How to setup test suite with dependent test cases

Tags: javascript, casperjs, web-testing, test-suite

How would I create a test suite where I have a test case that is dependent on a previous test case to start?

Example:

Test 1 Login with user X

Test 2 My account page (Comes after user logged in)

Test 3 "Follow up with other tests with the same user, but on other pages"

I've been through documentation of CasperJS writing_modules & other examples but I cannot find or understand how to set it up for my specific requirements.
Or if it's even possible to do so.

Currently I have it setup as follows:

**File 1 Suite**

```
// Suite.js 
var Suite;
Suite = require("./Login_User.js");
Suite.login_User("randomname","randompassword");

casper.then(function() { ;
    this.test.pass("Hit the first then");
    Suite = require("./MyAccount.js");
    Suite.Enterprise();;
});

casper.run(function() {
    return this.test.done();
});
```

**File 2 Login Functionality**

```
// Login_User.js (Test 2)

casper.test.begin("login page", function(test) {
    casper.options.waitTimeout = 5000;
    
    casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
        this.echo('rem msg: ' + msg);
    });
    
    casper.on("page.error", function(msg) {
        this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
    });
    
    var url = "https://website.com";
    
    casper.start(url, function() {
        console.log("page loaded");
    });

    exports.login_User = function(username, password) {
        casper.test.comment(username + "\n" + password);

        casper.then(function() {
            this.evaluate(function(username, password) {
                $("cmpLogin_UserName").val(username);
                $("cmpLogin_Password").val(password);
                $("cmpLogin_LoginButton").click();
            }, {
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            })
            casper.waitForUrl("https://website.com/myAccount.aspx", function() {
                console.log("Logged in");
                casper.capture("Loggedin.png");
            });
        });
        
        casper.then(function(){ 
            this.test.assertTitle("My Account", "Title is Login");
        });
        casper.run(function() {
            test.done();
        });
    }
});
```

**File 3 My Account Content**

```
// MyAccount (Test 3)
casper.test.begin("Account page", function(test) {
casper.options.waitTimeout = 5000;

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('rem msg: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

var url = "https://website.com/myAccount.aspx?";

casper.start(url, function() {
    console.log("page loaded");
    casper.capture("MyAccountEnt.png");
});

// It does not reach this section!!! 
exports.Enterprise = function() {
        casper.then(function() {
            this.test.assertTitle("My Account", "My Account page");
            this.test.pass("test test test");
        });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
}
});
```

**Command line output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mLy5.png

Comment: [The page object pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28129132/1816580) is basically the way to go.

Comment: This looks very confusing. I guess the problem lies in the nested `start` and `run` calls. During one execution with one `casper` instance, `start` and `run` should be used only once.